# Firebase 9.22 firebase-messaging-sw.js only onBackgroundMessage & onMessage event not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, web-push

Firebase 9.22 firebase-messaging-sw.js only onBackgroundMessage & onMessage event not working my service worker file given below:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getMessaging } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.0/firebase-messaging-sw.js'
import { onBackgroundMessage  } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.0/firebase-messaging-sw.js'
import { onMessage  } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.0/firebase-messaging.js'

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
  apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  measurementId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
});

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);
onBackgroundMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
});

onMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
  console.log('Message received. ', payload);
});
```